Disabling sessionState makes Actions be called twice
We currently are not using sessionState anymore, we are now relying on cookies with encrypted data that we used to save in the session before.
We had this function that was responsible for saving the data in the session, but currently we are only passing an empty string in for the value parameter.
        public static void SaveSession(object session_name, object value)
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            context.Session.Add(session_name.ToString(), value);
        }

Currently, it works fine like this (using an empty string until we fix this issue). But whenever I comment this code and I set the sessionState to mode="Off" in the Web.config, a lot of my Actions start to be called twice. And because of that, it starts to throw a lot of errors when it tries to grab anything from the DB, because the action that was hit first opens the DB and do what it needs to do, and in the meantime another thread tries to read the same action before the first one is finished (it is not an async Action). Since the first one has not yet closed the DB, the second one fails and that breaks the code. This is an example of an error that I am getting:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is connecting.'

And when I check my SQL Server, in this table (sys.dm_exec_sessions), I see that is creating a lot of sessions (checking the session_id column) at the same time, and eventually it hits a maximum and everything halts. This does not happen when I leave the sessionState on.
Remember that everything works as long as I leave the sessionState on, and I pass an empty string to that Action. Nothing else is using that Action anymore, so when I comment it I am still able to compile the project and everything. Any ideas would be very much appreciated!
